# Select-String successfully finds a string, replacing that found string with something else fails

Tags: powershell

uniquefile1.txt is a file that has no carriage returns (if it matters) and is very long. I am trying to match a variety of patterns.

1. The text file is not open when the program runs.
2. I visually have checked that the file has my pattern exactly as
   written, when using Select-String it confirms that the pattern
   exists.
3. When I go to replace, if I do `Out-Host` and search my
   output in my ide it does not show that it has changed. It is not
   replacing this string, and I do not know what I am doing wrong.
4. There are no errors of any kind when running my code.

I have tried:
`$file = Get-Content C:\Uniqueline1`

`$file.Replace($variableforpattern1, $varForReplacement) | Set-Content Uniquefile1.txt`

As well as the above except with the actual strings in place of the variables.

```
$file = Get-Content C:\uniquefile1.txt -Raw
$SEL = Select-String -Path "C:\uniquefile1.txt" -Pattern ">>>11^A"
if ($SEL = $true)
{
    write "true"
}
else
{
    write "not true"
}
$file -replace ">>>11^A", ">>>0111^A" | Set-Content "C:\uniquefile1.txt"
```

**AdminOfThings was correct, please see their comment. This character `^` has special meaning in Regex and must be escaped.**

Comment: `^` has special meaning in regex.  It must be escaped --> `$file -replace ">>>11\^A", ">>>0111^A" | Set-Content "C:\uniquefile1.txt"`

Comment: @AdminOfThings That was it. Thank you King. It is always something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-replace` uses regex for the search pattern and therefore must have regex-special characters escaped if they are to be matched literally. The `\` is used for escaping.

```
$file = Get-Content C:\uniquefile1.txt -Raw
$file -replace '>>>11\^A', '>>>0111^A' | Set-Content C:\uniquefile1.txt
```

`Select-String` without the `-SimpleMatch` switch uses regex as well. I don't know how that ever matched for you if the `-replace` operation failed.